# How to properly implement the following scale / bounce animation?

Tags: android, animation

I have the followin animation that scales an image from "invisible" to 60dp x 60dp adding a bounce effect. When this finishes it disappears with another scale effect

**bounce_animation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <set android:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce_interpolator">
        <scale
            android:fromXScale="0.1"
            android:fromYScale="0.1"
            android:toXScale="1.0"
            android:toYScale="1.0"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:duration="1600" />
    </set>
    <set>
        <scale
            android:startOffset="1900"
            android:duration="200"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:fromXScale="1.0"
            android:fromYScale="1.0"
            android:toXScale="0"
            android:toYScale="0" />
    </set>
</set>
```

This is my code to use this

**MainActivity.java**

```
        final ImageView likeBig = findViewById(R.id.like_big);
        final Animation bounceAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.bounce_animation);
        bounceAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                likeBig.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                likeBig.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
```

The problem is that when I do `likeBig.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` image becomes visible for a fraction of a second in full size before the scale animation starts. I need the image to be invisible until the animation begins.

What's wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I con only guess why the `View` is visible in full size at the beginning of the animation: maybe `onAnimationStart()` fires when the animation begins calculating the next changes but  before the screen is updated for the first time?

That being said, you can use [property animations](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation) instead of `View` animations to achieve the desired effect:

First, let your `View` have a size of just 1dp x 1dp in the beginning. Instead of setting a pivot, embed it at the center of a `FrameLayout` of size 60dp x 60dp. If required, you can set the visibility of the `FrameLayout` to `GONE` after the animation has finished (in this case, you need to register an [Animator.AnimatorListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator.AnimatorListener)).

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/like_big"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:background="#0000ff"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Next, the animations:

```
ObjectAnimator growX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(like_big,"scaleX", 1f, 60.0f);
ObjectAnimator growY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(like_big,"scaleY", 1f, 60.0f);
AnimatorSet growAnim = new AnimatorSet();
growAnim.playTogether(growX, growY);
growAnim.setDuration(1600);
growAnim.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());

ObjectAnimator shrinkX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(like_big,"scaleX", 60.0f, 0.0f);
ObjectAnimator shrinkY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(like_big,"scaleY", 60.0f, 0.0f);
AnimatorSet shrinkAnim = new AnimatorSet();
shrinkAnim.playTogether(shrinkX, shrinkY);
shrinkAnim.setDuration(200);
shrinkAnim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());

AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
animatorSet.playSequentially(growAnim, shrinkAnim);
```

Start the animation by calling

```
animatorSet.start();
```